# restart process executed in eshell in emacs

Tags: emacs, eshell

i have started a python process in eshell:

```
python app.py
```

i want to restart this with a elisp function, i think `comint-quit-subjob` when executed with `C-c C-\` kills the process but all my attempts to execute `comint-quit-subjob` have failed

This is what i have so far:

```
(defun restart-app()
  (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
    (interactive)
    (comint-quit-subjob)
    (eshell-return-to-prompt)
    (insert "python app.py")
    (eshell-send-input))
)
```

Hopefully it gives the jist of what i am trying, but it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for a eshell-ish way of killing a process (I am not a eshell user myself).  Comint tries to search something in the buffer.  You can workaround that doing something like this (but it is brittle and unelegant):

```
(defun restart-app()
  (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
    (interactive)
    (kill-process nil comint-ptyp)
    (run-with-timer 0.5 nil
                    (lambda ()
                      (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
                        (goto-char (point-max))
                        (insert "python app.py")
                        (eshell-send-input)))))
```